# How can 若い時 and ずっと work in this sentence?

Tags: syntax, tense, aspect

I'm trying to write

> "I have wanted to study Japanese from a young age"

And I have

> "若い時に私は日本語をずっと勉強したいです."

Does this work? How can I make it more correct?

Comment: に does not mean 'from'. The topic is generally found at the very beginning of the sentence. Why the の?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage of ずっと is just fine, but there are some other errors. A minimally corrected version is:

> 若い時**から**私は日本語をずっと勉強**したかったです**。

- に refers to one time point in the past. But your desire is a longstanding one that have remained even after you were no longer 若い. So you should use から ("from") instead.
- Your desire basically belongs to the past, so you need to use the past-form of 勉強したいです.

Optionally, you can express your longstanding desire up until now using ～ている, which is a way to express the continuation of an action. したい is an adjectival expression that does not straightforwardly connect to ている, but you can add と思う and say:

> 若い時から私は日本語をずっと勉強したい**と思っていました**。

This one is longer, but sounds more sophisticated and natural to me.

Comment: What is the difference between 若い時 and 若い頃？

Comment: @FelipeOliveira https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28545/5010 若い頃 would be more common, but 若い時 is not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

0) *From* a young age:

> 若いときから私は日本語をずっと勉強したいです。

1) You should drop the 私は, since you can't say ~たい on behalf of someone else. If there's a volition and it's not a question, it's strongly implied you're talking about yourself. (If it is indeed a question, that means you're asking someone about what they want, in a *very* direct manner. This should be avoided, unless among close friends/family).

> 若いときから日本語をずっと勉強したいです。

2) You want to put the volition in the past tense.

> 若いときから日本語をずっと勉強したかったです。

3) You should put the ずっと earlier on in the sentence. You'd *always* wanted to learn Japanse, but you hadn't wanted to be *constantly* learning Japanese.

> 若いときからずっと日本語を勉強したかったです。

4) As naruto says above, ～と思っている sounds less absolute and more natural.

> 若いときからずっと日本語を勉強したいと思っていました。

5) (Optionally:) If you're expressing your story among other people's stories, you might want to put the 私 back in, but at the front, to establish a context (i.e "speaking for myself, I've always wanted .." :

> 私は、若いときからずっと日本語を勉強したいと思っていました。