# What does "頃のこと" do in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The full sentence, from Anki core 2k/6k:

かつて私が学生だった頃のことです。

"That was when I was still a student."

I'm understanding "かつて私が学生だった" to mean "I was once a student," so I'm guessing the rest needs to account for "that was when." Is こと just the unnamed *thing* being referenced with the word "That" at the beginning of the English translation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the breakdown:

> (かつて私が学生だった→)**頃**
> **time** (←when I was once a student)
>
> の
> 's
>
> こと
> event
>
> ～です。
> (It) is ～.

こと refers to an event or occurrence rather than a "thing". 頃 is a noun that means "time" or "age" (See: [What is the difference between 頃 and とき?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28545/5010)), and かつて私が学生だった is modifying 頃 as a relative clause.

This use of の may seem unfamiliar, but English speakers say "*yesterday's* event", "*this year's* sales" and so on, so it should not be difficult to understand this.

Comment: Thanks, I think what threw me off was I was thinking of 頃 as something that would modify a previously mentioned period of time to make that period or point in time more approximate. As in Jisho's example: 大抵の晩餐は１１時頃に終わります。

Comment: @charlemagne That's true in this sentence, too. The difference is that what comes before 頃 is a relative clause in the sentence you asked. In this case, saying かつて私が学生だった**時**のことです wouldn't make much difference, though. Please see macraf's answer in the link.